# Input text pop up jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to show popup while the mouse pointer entering the input text id phonenumber, the ui is more like jquery datepicker but i need custom content on the popup, it wil load the tab-content Div

```
<div class="input-box">
 <input name="phonenumber" value="" id="phonenumber" type="text" class="input-text" title="Phone Number" />
</div>

 <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="select-box">
     <select>
      <option value="Reload Type">Reload Type</option>
      <option value="Prepaid">Prepaid</option>
      <option value="Post Paid">Post Paid</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   <div class="buttons-set">
    <button type="button" class="button" onclick=""><span><span>RECHARGE</span></span></button>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any plugins for popup? if not you can take a look into [Bootstrap Popover and Tool Tip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this](http://jsfiddle.net/g5xoj3r2/).

You can use a dialog or modal which comes in Jquery-UI with a little Jquery code.

```
    $('.tab-content').dialog({
        closeOnEscape: true,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
```